# Regular Expression RegEx challenge

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble with the following regular expression:
http://regex101.com/r/kH7eH4/3

The first part is what I want, but when I use ({{variable}}) in the "message" the regex stops too soon.
Any solutions?

My regex: `@@include\(\s*["\'](.*?)["\'](,\s*({[\s\S]*?})){0,1}\s*\)`

The test cases:

```
@@include('./partials/message_DE.html', {"message": "text with a {{variable}}","regards":"__('Groet, het SnappCar Team.')"})

@@include('./partials/message_DE.html', {"message": "text with a ({{variable}}) between brackets","regards":"__('Groet, het SnappCar Team.')"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `$` symbol (*End of the line anchor*) at the last.

```
@@include\(\s*["\'](.*?)["\'](,\s*({[\s\S]*?})){0,1}\s*\)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kH7eH4/4)

OR

Use a lookahead.

```
@@include\(\s*["\'](.*?)["\'](,\s*({[\s\S]*?})){0,1}\s*\)(?=\s+@@|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kH7eH4/8)

Comment: this is correct! but It's not a given that there's always a line break, there could be more than one @@include statement on a line. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: But it solves your current question. could you provide some examples.